# exclude some fields in tastypie post data

Tags: python, django, tastypie

recently i  start an API for my project by `django-tastypie`. actually I want to exclude some field requirement in post requests.

Assume that my model have four fields and all of them defined as require in `django` model. But I want to receive two of them from API request and 2 others will be filled by my functions.

So, how could I tell to `tastypie` to receive just those two fields and skip others?

Comment: Did you follow the tutorial on http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to exclude same fields you can do that by define it in the meta class of the Resource, for example:

```
class MyResource(ModelResource):
     class Meta:
         excludes = (field1, field2)
```

And those fields will be excluded every time for this resource.

But if you want only on post to get different fields the way how I am doing that is by overriding dehydrate method:

```
def dehydrate(self, bundle):
     if bundle.request.META['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST':
         bundle.data = dict(my_field1=bundle.obj.my_func1(),
                            my_field2=bundle.obj.my_func2()
                            )
     return bundle
```

Comment: `excludes` doesn't protect you against POST. You are still able to create new object with `my_field1` and `my_field2`. Also `dehydrate` should be `hydrate`.

Comment: If excludes doesn't protect you against POST, how do you protect the resource from updating excluded fields? Thanks.