# Django tastypie query has unnecessary inner join. DRF is fast. Why

Tags: django, tastypie

I have 2 tables, and just want to simply get all items in seconds table 'Book'. No need to any information from 'Author' table.

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, primary_key=True, db_index=True)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, primary_key=True, db_index=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, db_index=True)


class AuthorResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta(object):
        queryset = Author.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ('get', 'post', 'put', 'delete')
        always_return_data = True
        filtering = { 'name' : ALL }


class BookResource(ModelResource):
    author_id = fields.IntegerField(attribute='author__id')

    class Meta(object):
        queryset = Book.objects.select_related().all()
        allowed_methods = ('get', 'post', 'put', 'delete')
        always_return_data = True
        filtering = {'title',
                      'author' : ALL_WITH_RELATIONS}
```

It is extremely slow, and I noticed that Tasktypie doing a lot of inner join, which I don't care about. I only need information from table Book. Not any information from Author table.

I implemented same web service API with REST Framework, I did not notice the speed issue.

In my real project, it is about 3 table, 2 table has about 100 record each, 3rd table has about 800 records. Tastypie take about 1 minutes to load, REST Framework takes few seconds. After switching to use Tastypie, it basically not work. Too slow.

What cause the performance issue? Am I doing the right thing?

I am new to use Tastypie, not sure if I am doing correct query. Should I use hydrate/dehydrate, obj_get_list to do this simple query? What's correct way to do this very basic query.

Answer (score 0):

you can exclude the fields if you don't want. See this question. [exclude some fields in tastypie post data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010366/exclude-some-fields-in-tastypie-post-data)

OR

you can get the data by using ToManyField instead of **select_related**. http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#tomanyfield

Comment: I noticed there are extra queries in log which I am total not interested in. I don't know why it is there. For example, I want to retrieve 1 row from Book model. I want all fields: title, author (foreign key id). I noticed 2 queries performed: #1 is query Book model, #2 is query Author model. #2 is waste of time, no need at all. How to get rid of. I have nested few tables, #2 could become really slow. I feel I don't understand Tastypie or django filter. Please help.